# Implement BST using comparable or comparator

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I'm trying to create a generic `BinarySearchTree<T>` class. I want to provide two options (constructors),

1. Empty constructor for a generic class which implements `Comparable<T>` i.e. If `Dog` is a class which implements `Comparable<Dog>`, then:

   `BinarySearchTree<Dog> bst = new BinarySearchTree<Dog>();`
2. Pass a `Comparator<T>` for a generic class which need not have implemented `Comparable<T>`, i.e. If **Dog** is a class (did not implement `Comparable<Dog>`) and **DogComp** is a class which implements `Comparator<Dog>` then

   `BinarySearchTree<Dog> bst = new BinarySearchTree<Dog>(new DogComp());`

I have a Comparator field in my BinarySearchTree class. For empty consrtuctor, I will create new comparator. If comparator is passed, I will simply assign it to that comparator field.

How should I declare class and constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to improve on bot's answer:

Make the `BinarySearchTree` class abstract, with an abstract `compare` method. Two inner static concrete classes can then implement both schemes. Instead of a constructor, provide two construction methods like:

```
public static <E> BinarySearchTree<E> create(Comparator<? super E> comp) {
    return new ComparatorSearchTree(comp);
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> BinarySearchTree<E> create() {
    return new ComparableSearchTree();
}
```

This way the rest of the class can just use your compare(one, other) method without caring about whether the result is from a comparator or the natural element order.

You may have noticed that I specified `comp` as `Comparator<? super E>`. This means that the comparator is *contravariant*. This makes your search tree more flexible, because this way you can put in any comparator that is able to compare E objects, even if the comparator only compares F objects where F is a superclass of E.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the actual logic that will be used for deciding where to insert a node, this is what you can do :

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> {

    private Node root;
    private Comparator<T> comparator;

    public BinarySearchTree() {

    }

    public BinarySearchTree(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public void insert(T obj) {
        // binary search tree logic for deciding where to insert the node
        // Create a Node
        // ....
        // comparison of two nodes
        if (obj instanceof Comparable) {
            // compare using Comparable
        } else if (comparator != null) {
            // compare using Comparator
        } else {
            //objects cannot be compared
        }
    }

    /*Represents a node for the tree */
    private class Node {
        T obj;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        public Node(T obj) {
            super();
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that instead of the instanceOf check on each new insert, you can add that check in the constructor itself and throw and exception if your data does not implement comparable or comparator.

Comment: The problem is that the user would have to provide a comparator when the tree is initialized, even if the tree holds comprarable-type keys